nextjs - adding MongoDBAdapter to next-auth file causes error with GoogleProvider login
I was following a YouTube tutorial on making an ecommerce app with NextJS, next-auth, and MongoDB when I encountered this error. I then found an article on Medium discussing adding next-auth and MongoDB to a NextJS app, and the code is virtually identical.
I have a very basic NextJS app with next-auth, mongodb and @auth/mongodb-adapter installed. The sign-in using Google works until I add one specific line to use MongoDBAdapter. Then I get a bunch of errors in my terminal like MongoServerSelectionError, adapter_error_getuserbyaccount, oauth_callback_handler_error and such. Also, on the UI, once that one line is added and I try to sign in, the UI shows a block from Google saying "Try signing in with a different account".
I have verified all the environment variables. Here is the code:
pages/index.js
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
    
        Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>

      </>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn('google')}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  )
}

pages/_app.js
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}

lib/mongodb.js
// This approach is taken from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import clientPromise from '@/lib/mongodb';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),   ******THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE******
});

Without the offending line, the sign-in works, even with all of the MongoDB imports. It is simply that line addition that screws it up. The one thing that is different between the tutorials and my code is this import:
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";

In the tutorials, it is like this:
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";

I tried various ways to import the adapter at @next-auth instead of @auth, but those threw their own errors. And of course the next-auth website says to use @auth/mongodb-adapter, so it appears to be their change. I don't know why that would cause the error, but who knows. Anyway, any help is appreciated.

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import clientPromise from '@/lib/mongodb';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),   ******THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE******
  session: {
    strategy:"jwt",
  },
});

adding session: { strategy:"jwt" } seemed to solve my issue revolving MongoDBAdapter.
